# Include domain along with username in PuTTY

Tags: ssh, putty

I want to save a profile in PuTTY and include my username. Usually I would enter host name as `user@host`. But in this case I have to also include a domain with my username, `user@domain.local` for instance. How can I include the username, domain and host in PuTTY? Or, shall I put the user and domain information elsewhere.

The goal is to avoid login prompts (using private key authentication).

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. You can just enter `user@domain.local` and save it as you normally would, it should work.

Comment: Are you suggesting I enter the "host name" as `user@domain.local@host`?

Comment: Why are you using the `@` sign twice? Is that a typo or? If it's a typo, yes, you should just enter `user@domain.local` as hostname, click default settings and then click save.

Comment: Because I am logging on to `host` using username `user` and the domain `domain.local`. I can't use a straight username, have to include the logon domain as well. That's the essence of my question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this. As far as I know you can only use the `user@host:port` syntax, where host can be a domain name or an IP address. Does this syntax work for you without saving? If so, just enter it as you normally would and hit save. Putty will save anything you've entered into the program and won't check anything. **Edit** or is your username `user@domain.local` and your host `host`?

Comment: Correct, the username is username and domain, `user@domain.local`. That's the foundation of my quandary.

Answer (score 4):

In the end, `user@domain.local@host` actually worked fine.