# how to enter a username within a domain in a Putty ssh session

Tags: ssh, putty

I am using Putty to establish an SSH connection to my local server. After typing the IP address of the server (host), and establishing the connection successfully, I have an issue on how to enter the username if the user is in a domain.

for example:

```
domain: EMEA

username: sam.alan

host IP: 192.168.2.3
```

I tried those two format approaches:

```
login as: EMEA\sam.alen

Network error: Software caused connection abort.
```

```
login as: sam.alen@EMEA

sam.alen@EMEA@192.168.2.3's password:

Access denied
```

The password I am entering is definitely correct. It seems like an issue with the username/domain format.

Comment: Can you provide the OpenSSH server logs during this connection attempt.

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://superuser.com/questions/781411/include-domain-along-with-username-in-putty

Comment: Have you tried `sam.alen@EMEA@192.168.2.3?`

Comment: @Ramhound , from Logging tab, I added log file putty.log and select all session output option, but it doesn't tell much more, same output for each case.  so first case:
Network error: Software caused connection abort.  and second case: Access denied

Comment: @stickynotememo the answer in this question suggest to add it in this way:  sam.alen@EMEA@192.168.2.3 but unfortunately not work for me. the output in this case also "Access denied"  . even I try from power shell directly by writing this command:
ssh sam.alen@EMEA@192.168.2.3
then I get :
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.2.3' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
sam.alen@EMEA@192.168.2.3's password:[ my_password]

Permission denied, please try again.

Comment: This is not about PowerShell/PuTTY/whatever SSH client you are using. This is about your server.

Comment: Indeed. Have you checked your server settings to see if it even allows ssh connections?